# Cannot connect to SQL Server From Clients in LAN

Tags: sql-server, dns, active-directory

Yesterday I had no problems.  Now when any client (even MSSMS from a client machine) tries to access sql server located on a server in the domain I get the following error:  TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to SERVER\Instance

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. ...

SQL server is 2014 on a Windows 2012 R2 Server which also hosts the Active Directory.
I can connect using MSSMS from the server itself to the database. The log states that the service started and is listening on port 63782.  I can also connect to sql server from the host machine using ip:port (192.168.0.2, 63782).  But I cannot connect to it this way from the clients.  (I made no changes to the firewall and the rule for lan-lan is allow all services and all connections).

Shared Memory, TCP/IP and Named Pipes are enabled on the sql server configuration Manager.
I can ping to the server from the clients and to the clients from the server.

The main difference between yesterday and today is that I had to reinstall the DNS on the server.  The DNS appears to be working very well and I can't find any DNS errors on the server.   I don't think its the firewall but I added two rules that allow UDP and TCP specifically within the local network (even though there is a policy which allows all traffic within the local network).

I am at a loss and would appreciate some assistance into solving the problem or even where to look.

Comment: Try to connect using IP,port

Comment: I managed to find a solution.  In my re-installation of DNS I followed the recommendation to have only the server's DNS registered on the NIC.  When I added the ISP's IP to the NIC of the DNS server, then the clients were able to resolve the sql server.  This is somewhat of a mystery to me as the address of the sql server is on the local DNS.